# How to center verticaly n inline containers with different font-size?

Tags: css

I just discovered the `display: table` and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle` method to align divs verticaly today.

I am using it at many places of my code, but i meet a specific case where i can't make it works!

When i want to verticaly align n elements containing elements which has the same `font-size`, everything works fine, but if i want a text bigger on one `inline` elements than others, here is what happens:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="left"><span>LEFT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="middle"><span>MIDDLE</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right"><span>RIGHT</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color:red;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
}
.left {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    display:inline-table;
    background-color:blue;
}
.middle {
    height: 100%;
    width: 60%;
    display:inline-table;
    background-color:orange;
}
.right {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    display:inline-table;
    background-color:green;
}
span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.middle span {
    font-size:5em;
}
```

RESULTS:

[image]

[Here is a JSFiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/bYqS6/)

How to avoid that? Maybe there is a better way than the `inline-table` trick for that case?

Comment: In you example you can put `.menu > div { vertical-align:middle; }`.

Comment: You're welcome Ludo! Are your working on a Chrome App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just vertical align the direct children of the container, in your case this will do the job:

```css
.menu > div { 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add a fixed line height to the spans:

```
.menu span { line-height: 50px;}
```